# WooCommerce Booking calendor not showing

Tags: woocommerce, woocommerce-bookings

My website was working fine and showing the calender for Appointment booking using the WooCommerce Bookings plugin but in the last few weeks, calendars stopped working and were not shown on the front end.

Following error is show on Inspect Element Console

```
date-picker.js:1064 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '2022-8-29')
    at o.getDateElementAttributes (date-picker.js:1064:26)
    at o.maybe_load_from_cache (date-picker.js:712:21)
    at e._generateHTML (datepicker.min.js?ver=1.13.1:9:30695)
    at e._updateDatepicker (datepicker.min.js?ver=1.13.1:9:14501)
    at e._refreshDatepicker (datepicker.min.js?ver=1.13.1:9:9945)
    at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (datepicker.min.js?ver=1.13.1:9:36351)
    at Function.each (jquery.min.js?ver=3.6.0:2:3003)
    at s.fn.init.each (jquery.min.js?ver=3.6.0:2:1481)
    at V.fn.datepicker (datepicker.min.js?ver=1.13.1:9:36283)
    at Object.refresh_datepicker (date-picker.js:263:12)
o.getDateElementAttributes @ date-picker.js:1064
o.maybe_load_from_cache @ date-picker.js:712
_generateHTML @ datepicker.min.js?ver=1.13.1:9
_updateDatepicker @ datepicker.min.js?ver=1.13.1:9
_refreshDatepicker @ datepicker.min.js?ver=1.13.1:9
(anonymous) @ datepicker.min.js?ver=1.13.1:9
each @ jquery.min.js?ver=3.6.0:2
each @ jquery.min.js?ver=3.6.0:2
V.fn.datepicker @ datepicker.min.js?ver=1.13.1:9
refresh_datepicker @ date-picker.js:263
(anonymous) @ date-picker.js:689
c @ jquery.min.js?ver=3.6.0:2
fireWith @ jquery.min.js?ver=3.6.0:2
(anonymous) @ date-picker.js:861
c @ jquery.min.js?ver=3.6.0:2
fireWith @ jquery.min.js?ver=3.6.0:2
l @ jquery.min.js?ver=3.6.0:2
(anonymous) @ jquery.min.js?ver=3.6.0:2
load (async)
send @ jquery.min.js?ver=3.6.0:2
ajax @ jquery.min.js?ver=3.6.0:2
s.ajax.s.ajax @ jquery-migrate.min.js?ver=3.3.2:2
o.get_data @ date-picker.js:825
o.create @ date-picker.js:687
date_picker_init @ date-picker.js:256
(anonymous) @ date-picker.js:30
each @ jquery.min.js?ver=3.6.0:2
each @ jquery.min.js?ver=3.6.0:2
init @ date-picker.js:25
(anonymous) @ date-picker.js:1152
e @ jquery.min.js?ver=3.6.0:2
t @ jquery.min.js?ver=3.6.0:2
setTimeout (async)
(anonymous) @ jquery.min.js?ver=3.6.0:2
c @ jquery.min.js?ver=3.6.0:2
fireWith @ jquery.min.js?ver=3.6.0:2
fire @ jquery.min.js?ver=3.6.0:2
c @ jquery.min.js?ver=3.6.0:2
fireWith @ jquery.min.js?ver=3.6.0:2
ready @ jquery.min.js?ver=3.6.0:2
B @ jquery.min.js?ver=3.6.0:2
```

Can anyone help me with this issue?

WordPress version 6.0.2
PHP Version 7.4
Woocommerce version 6.8.2
WooCommerce Bookings version 1.15.60

Thank you in advance

Comment: Clear any cache ? Disable and reactivate plugins could help too. Could be conflict with other plguins too.

Comment: I have tried everything mentioned by you @MartinMirchev nothing has worked

Comment: From my understanding the error its telling you that date format its wrong - '2022-8-29'. Its premium plugin so contact devs or if there is option to change the date format try that first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution.

I was using Real Time find and replace plugin to replace few words on the front end to the website so while doing that I was breaking the plugin functionality as the words were replaced in coding as well. Disabled the Plugin and replaced words using CSS and not the website is working fine.

Thank you for all the suggestions.